# JQuery slideUp doesn't work when taking id from data attribute

Tags: jquery

I am experimenting with JQuery and am trying to get one element to slideDown / slideUp when another element is clicked, taking the id of the target element from a data attribute of the clicked element.

http://jsfiddle.net/muqz7/1/

There seems to be activity in the DOM in the inspector, but visually nothing changes. My code:

HTML:

```
<button data-target="#box">Click me!</button>
<div id="box"></div>
```

CSS:

```
.box {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: red;
    display: none;
}
```

JQuery:

```
$('button').click(function() {
    box = $($(this).data('target'));
    if (box.hasClass('open')) {
        box.removeClass('open');
        box.slideUp(400);
    } else {
        box.addClass('open');
        box.slideDown(400);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your css `.box` to `#box`

Check the demo http://jsfiddle.net/yeyene/muqz7/2/

```
$('button').click(function() {
    box = $($(this).data('target'));
    if (box.hasClass('open')) {
        box.removeClass('open');
        box.slideUp(400);
    } else {
        box.addClass('open');
        box.slideDown(400);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

In your CSS, you need to write #box instead of .box since you're using the id, not the class.

Answer (score 1):

its working for me here:

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lb3GA/)

I changed the html to

```
<button data-target="#box">Click me!</button>
<div id="box">
    test<br>
    test<br>
    test<br>
    test<br>
    test<br>
    test<br>
</div>
```